# ServerSoket checkOldImpl method What's the use?

Tags: java

When reading the java source code, the checkOldImpl method in ServerSocket does not find that he is actually useful. From the name, he checks the old Impl but the impl has been replaced when using it. Is the old here referring to SocketImpl? Is the implementation of the old version? If so, why is the new version already having a new SocketImpl` left?

jdk1.8

```
private void checkOldImpl() {
    if (impl == null)
        return;
    // SocketImpl.connect() is a protected method, therefore we need to use
    // getDeclaredMethod, therefore we need permission to access the member
    try {
        AccessController.doPrivileged(
            new PrivilegedExceptionAction<Void>() {
                public Void run() throws NoSuchMethodException {
 impl.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("connect",SocketAddress.class,int.class);
                    return null;
                }
            });
    } catch (java.security.PrivilegedActionException e) {
        oldImpl = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What this code is doing, is checkout whether the class that was set as the `impl` (`SocketImpl`) has declared a method `connect(SocketAddress a, int b)` itself (not inherited).

If it doesn't have that method, `getDeclaredMethod` throws a `NoSuchMethodException`. This exception gets converted to a `PrivilegedActionException` by `PrivilegedExceptionAction`.

So if the method doesn't exist, this code sets the flag `oldImpl` to the value `true`. This flag is later used to make some decisions.

To answer your question more directly:

- `oldImpl` doesn't refer to the previous value of `impl` - instead, it's a `boolean` flag that indicates whether the current value of `impl` is "old" (because it doesn't have a particular method)

Comment: But SocketImpl is an abstract method. Basically, isn't he implementing the connect method? If it is multiple inheritance, then can I override a method? Why do you have to declare connect? I can completely override one of the methods in the base and PlainSocketImpl instead of rewriting connect.